# method call expected error while executing Asynctask

Tags: java, android, methods, interface, android-asynctask

I am trying to return value from Asynctask by creating an interface but while executing Asynctask class , its giving me method call expected error .
I am getting the error in line  `longoperation(dir1, asyncTask1).execute();`

How do I fix it ?

```
public interface IAsyncTask {

    ArrayList<String> IAmFinished(ArrayList<File> arrayList)
 }

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements IAsyncTask {

    public static ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    Longoperation longoperation = new Longoperation(dir1,this);
    IAsyncTask asyncTask1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        dir1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        longoperation(dir1, asyncTask1).execute();
        JazzyListView lv = (JazzyListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        IAmFinished(fileList);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name));
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> IAmFinished(ArrayList<File> list) {
        for(int i=0;i< list.size();i++){
            name.add(list.get(i).getName());
        }
        return name;
    }

    private class Longoperation extends AsyncTask<File, Void, ArrayList<File>>{

        File dir;
        public IAsyncTask asyncTaskListener;

        public Longoperation(File dir,IAsyncTask asyncTaskListener) {
            this.dir = dir;
            this.asyncTaskListener = asyncTaskListener;
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<File> doInBackground(File... params) {
            File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
            if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                        doInBackground(listFile[i]);

                    } else {

                        boolean booleanpdf = false;
                        if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".zip") || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jar")) {

                            for (int j = 0; j < fileList.size(); j++) {
                                if (fileList.get(j).getName().equals(listFile[i].getName())) {
                                    booleanpdf = true;
                                } else {

                                }
                            }

                            if (booleanpdf) {
                                booleanpdf = false;
                            } else {
                                fileList.add(listFile[i]);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return fileList;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<File> list) {
            asyncTaskListener.IAmFinished(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `longoperation(dir1, asyncTask1)` as you are using. Objects are not functions, so you can't use it like them.

Change the following code `Longoperation longoperation = new Longoperation(dir1,this);` to  `Longoperation longoperation`. Then change `longoperation(dir1, asyncTask1).execute();` to `longoperation = new Longoperation(dir1, this);`